# How to select rows which are evenly distributed on some column?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table `tbl` with 3 columns `imp_col, data1, data2` where `imp_col's` type is `enum('imp1', 'imp2, 'imp3', 'imp4')`. Now if I want to select 10 rows randomly I can do like this.

```
select imp_col, data1, data2 from tbl where imp_col in ('imp1', 'imp2', 'imp3') limit 10 order by rand();
```

But in this case all the 10 resulting rows may have `imp_col` as `imp1`. 
Is there an SQL query which can return 10 rows with `imp_col` distributed evenly among `imp1, imp2, imp3`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to use limit and rand() in an inline view in mySQL?

```
      select Y.c1, Y.c2, Y.c3
      from
      (
      select c1, c2, c3.... from X limit 500 order by rand()
      ) as Y
      where Y.c2 in ( 'imp1', 'imp2', 'imp3')
      limit 10
```

That would give you a better chance of getting a variety of 'imp' values, if it's legal.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with

```
imp_col LIKE "imp1"
OR imp_col LIKE "imp2"
OR imp_col LIKE "imp3"
```

I think IN doesn't works for enums